# Adding a click handler to toggle divs

Tags: jquery

I want to add click handler to `<a id='3'>`. I have a main `div` in which `<link-div>`s are getting added dynamically and shown as a list. I have only posted the code that is buggy minus the CSS and other goodies. I cant figure out how to isolate that `<a>` for each `<link-div>`. Idea is to click and show hidden `<div id="hide">` based on whether it resides in first `<link-div>` or 2nd.

Here is [fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ntt33/)

### HTML

```
  <div id="main">
    <div id="link-div">
      <div class="name-div">               
       <a id='1' href='javascript:void(0);' >(11)</a> 
       <a id='2' href='javascript:void(0);'> Apples </a>
       <a id='3' href='javascript:void(0);'>[click to see more]</a>
      <div id="hide">more apples </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  <div id="link-div"> 
    <div class="name-div">               
      <a id='1' href='javascript:void(0);' > (44) </a> 
      <a id='2' href='javascript:void(0);'>  Bats </a>
      <a id='3' href='javascript:void(0);'>[click  to see more]</a>
      <div id="hide"> more bats</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
## Javascript

  $("#main div div div").hide(); /*hide 'more apples', more bats'*/ 

  $("#main div div div > a ").click(function() { /* this is where I need help */
   $("#main div div div").toggle();  /*show 'more apples' or 'more bats' */
  });
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: it is not clear on click of which `a` elements you want to toggle

Comment: `#main div div div` what do you expect from this? Oh I see, you want to select `#hide`, it would be easier to just give a class to your hide's and to your links that should trigger the toggle

Comment: #main div div div should give me <div id="hide"> world</div>

Comment: It also gives you `<div id="hide"> hello</div>`.

Comment: It worked! http://jsfiddle.net/Ntt33/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse IDs, they have to be unique. Use classes for repeating elements.

```
<div class="name-div">               
   <a class='1' href='javascript:void(0);' > B b</a> 
   <a class='2' href='javascript:void(0);'>  B b </a>
   <a class='toggle' href='javascript:void(0);'>click Me me say world</a>
   <div class="hide"> world</div>
</div>
```

Then apply the click handler to the class, and use DOM traversal to find the associated element that you want to toggle.

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".hide").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no anchor elements `<a></a>` defined in the div you are trying to access

`$("#main div div div")` will find `<div id="hide"> hello </div>`